# Use eventChannel to get real time data from Firestore

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-saga, saga

I would like to sync my data in React with Firestore, each time some data is changed I would like to have an update/refresh of my data.

For fetching the data I have:

```
function*  syncCustomers() {
    try {
        const response = yield call(fireBaseBackend.getCustomersAPI);
        yield put(loadCustomers(response));
    } catch (error) {
        yield put(customerError(error));
    }
}
```

Where my getCustomersAPI is:

```
getCustomersAPI = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        firebase.firestore().collection("customers").onSnapshot((snap) => {
            let documents = [];
            snap.docs.forEach(doc => {
                let result = doc.data();
                result.uid = doc.id;
                documents.push(result);
            });
            resolve(documents);
        });
    });
};
```

This works to get my data, for the real time I implemented:

```
function* usersChannelSaga () {
    try {
        while (true) {
            const response = yield call(fireBaseBackend.getCustomersAPI);
            yield put(loadCustomers(response));
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
        yield put(customerError(error));
    }
}
```

But I would like to use the eventChannel for this. How does this need to be implemented?
I tried:

```
function* usersChannelSaga () {
    const channel = eventChannel(emit => fireBaseBackend.syncCustomers(emit));
    try {
        while (true) {
            const data = yield take(channel);
            yield put(loadCustomers(response));
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
        yield put(customerError(error));
    }
}
```

Where syncCustomers is :

```
  syncCustomers(emit){
        return firebase.firestore().collection("customers").onSnapshot(emit);
    }
```

Anyone an idea how to solve this?